# Python 3: How to generate a table from a nested list as input

Tags: python-3.x, nmap

So, I've got the following nested list (which I've parsed from an Nmap XML output file). It's basically a list of IP addresses, and all their open ports:

```
[['192.168.23.78', ['53', '88', '135', '139', '389', '445', '3389']],
 ['192.168.27.243', ['135', '139', '445', '3389', '5800', '5900']],
 ['192.168.99.164', ['135', '139', '445', '3389', '5800', '5900']],
 ['192.168.228.211', ['80']],
 ['192.168.171.74', ['135', '139', '445', '3389', '5800', '5900']]]
```

I would like to create a table from this data, where each first item (all IP addresses) are printed as rows. I then wish to iterate over each second item (a list of all ports per IP address), and count each unique port number. I wish this new counted unique list of ports to be printed as column headers of my table. My empty table should then roughly look like this:

```
                 53  80  88  135  139  389  445  3389  5800  5900
192.168.23.78
192.168.27.243
192.168.99.164
192.168.228.211
192.168.171.74
```

And then I wish to place X's in each correct cell for each IP address that has a given open port, like so:

```
                 53  80  88  135  139  389  445  3389  5800  5900
192.168.23.78    X   X       X    X    X         X
192.168.27.243               X    X         X    X     X     X
192.168.99.164               X    X         X    X     X     X
192.168.228.211      X
192.168.171.74               X    X         X    X     X     X
```

How would I do this with my data set?

I'm a total newbie, but I could likely figure out how to iterate over all the port numbers and get a unique port list. But I have absolutely not clue how to then plot X's on the table, in the correct cells

This is my code so far:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

from pprint import pprint
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def loopy(item):
    for port in host.findall('ports/port'):
        if port.get('protocol') == "tcp":
            portid = port.get('portid')
            for state in port.findall('state'):
                if state.get('state') == "open":
                    if item == "address":
                        list_addr.append(addr)
                        return
                    elif item == "portid":
                        list_portid.append(portid)

root = ET.parse('scan5.xml').getroot()
result = []
for host in root.findall('host'):
    list_portid = []
    list_addr = []
    address = host.find('address')
    addr = address.get('addr')
    loopy("address")
    loopy("portid")
    if list_addr:
        result.append([list_addr[0], list_portid])

pprint(result)
```

My nested list is in now `result`, but I have no clue how to create a table from this.

So far my code only produces the raw list:

```
[['10.133.23.78', ['53', '88', '135', '139', '389', '445', '3389']],
 ['10.133.27.243', ['135', '139', '445', '3389', '5800', '5900']],
 ['10.133.99.164', ['135', '139', '445', '3389', '5800', '5900']],
 ['10.135.228.211', ['80']],
 ['10.133.171.74', ['135', '139', '445', '3389', '5800', '5900']]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use install and use prettytable package to visualise pretty table

first `pip install prettytable`

then code

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable

data = [['192.168.23.78', ['53', '88', '135', '139', '389', '445', '3389']],
        ['192.168.27.243', ['135', '139', '445', '3389', '5800', '5900']],
        ['192.168.99.164', ['135', '139', '445', '3389', '5800', '5900']],
        ['192.168.228.211', ['80']],
        ['192.168.171.74', ['135', '139', '445', '3389', '5800', '5900']]]

ports = sorted(set([int(port) for _, open_ports in data for port in open_ports]))

my_table = PrettyTable()
header = ['ip']
header.extend(ports)
my_table.field_names = header
for ip_address, open_ports in data:
    row = [ip_address]
    row.extend('X' if str(port) in open_ports else '' for port in ports)
    my_table.add_row(row)

print(my_table)
```

output

```
+-----------------+----+----+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+------+------+
|        ip       | 53 | 80 | 88 | 135 | 139 | 389 | 445 | 3389 | 5800 | 5900 |
+-----------------+----+----+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+------+------+
|  192.168.23.78  | X  |    | X  |  X  |  X  |  X  |  X  |  X   |      |      |
|  192.168.27.243 |    |    |    |  X  |  X  |     |  X  |  X   |  X   |  X   |
|  192.168.99.164 |    |    |    |  X  |  X  |     |  X  |  X   |  X   |  X   |
| 192.168.228.211 |    | X  |    |     |     |     |     |      |      |      |
|  192.168.171.74 |    |    |    |  X  |  X  |     |  X  |  X   |  X   |  X   |
+-----------------+----+----+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+------+------+
```

Comment: This is great, thanks a lot! Is there also a way to output this in a CSV format, in an "exhaustive" way? I mean that, for example, let's take IP 192.168.228.211. That line should then be formatted as: 192.168.228.211,,X,,,,,,,,

Comment: yes, just write the `header` and each `row` to the csv file. use `csv` module for that. You can write each row or append it to some variable (e.g. table_rows) and write all rows at once at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Using `numpy` and `pandas` you could do

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

table = [['192.168.23.78', ['53', '88', '135', '139', '389', '445', '3389']],
         ['192.168.27.243', ['135', '139', '445', '3389', '5800', '5900']],
         ['192.168.99.164', ['135', '139', '445', '3389', '5800', '5900']],
         ['192.168.228.211', ['80']],
         ['192.168.171.74', ['135', '139', '445', '3389', '5800', '5900']]]

# Collect the ip_addresses
ip_addresses = [el[0] for el in table]

# Collect the column names. Temporarily convert to integers to sort them properly
columns = sorted(np.unique([c for el in table for c in el[1]]), key = lambda x: int(x))


# Initialize numpy matrix to hold strings
table_matrix = np.zeros((len(ip_addresses), len(columns)), str)

for row in table:
    # Get the row index of the IP address
    for i, ip in enumerate(ip_addresses):
        if row[0] == ip:
            rdx = i
    # Check which columns have values in the row that corresponds to the IP address    
    for c in row[1]:
        for j, col in enumerate(columns):
            # Add an X if the row has that column
            if c == col:
                table_matrix[rdx, j] = 'X'

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(table_matrix, index = ip_addresses, columns = columns)
```

Output:

```
Out[24]: 
                53 80 88 135 139 389 445 3389 5800 5900
192.168.23.78    X     X   X   X   X   X    X          
192.168.27.243             X   X       X    X    X    X
192.168.99.164             X   X       X    X    X    X
192.168.228.211     X                                  
192.168.171.74             X   X       X    X    X    X
```

Comment: Note that the empty cells in the dataframe are filled with empty string like `''`. To change them to `NaN` values, you can do `df = df.replace({'': np.nan})`